# How to save error to core data or convert to Data?

Tags: swift, core-data, error-handling, swift3

I have error enum which is inherited from the *Error protocol* like this:

```
enum SGError: Error {
    case error1
    case error2
}
let error = SGError.error1
```

How I could save **error** variable to core data? Or how I could convert **error** to *Data* (*NSData*)?

And later I would need to convert back *Data* (*NSData*) to SGError.

Comment: let data = error_string.data(using: .utf8) if error is in string.

Comment: @Swift_Guru Could you please write more info. Current your post not working.

Comment: I am not sure but have you tried  let data = error.data(using: .utf8)

Comment: @Swift_Guru It can not be done like this.

Comment: I suppose you have to convert the raw value of your enum

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @DaveWeston Lets say I am uploading files to the server. During upload can be a problems/errors for some files. I would like to save error why did it failed and later user could see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error enum would have rawValue I needed to inherit from Int as well. Below is example.

```
enum SGError: Int, Error {
    case error1
    case error2
}
let error = SGError.error1

// Set & save error to the core data.
managedObject.error = error.rawValue

// Get back error from core data.
let error = SGError(rawValue: managedObject.error)
```